# Set $resource transformResponse after initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Is there anyway to set the `transformResponse` after initialization of a `$resource`?

I basically have an extended `$resource`, but I want to attach a `transformResponse` to the extended version, and not the original.

```
angular.module("services").factory('MyObject', function($resource) {
  var MyObject = $resource('/my/object.json');

  MyObject.prototype.someBusinessLogic = function() {};

  return MyObject;
});


angular.module("services").factory('MyExtendedObject', function($resource, MyObject) {
  MyObject.prototype.someExtendedBusinessLogic = function() {};

  return MyObject;
});
```

So in that example I want to set the `transformResponse` to something like this (only in `MyExtendedObject`):

```
$resource('/my/object.json', {}, {
  query: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: true,
    transformResponse: function(data) {
      var objects = angular.fromJson(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i] = new MyExtendedObject(objects[i]);
        objects[i].hash = JSON.stringify(objects[i]);
      }
      return objects;
    }
  }
});
```

The purpose for this is to check if any object have been changed before saving them in bulk.

If I'm am way off the par, can you suggest a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You're modifying the prototype of `MyObject` in your factory function for `MyExtendedObject`, so you're not creating a second resource type, so there is no such thing as "only in `MyExtendedObject`.

Comment: @imaginaryboy ok, so is there a way to achieve something similar to what I am trying?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just tap into the `$promise` that `$resource` gives you...

```
angular.module("services").factory('MyExtendedObject', function($resource, MyObject) {
 MyObject.get({whatever:'here'}).$promise.then(function(result){
    var transformedStuff = result; 
    //<!--do transform stuff here-->
    return transformedStuff;
  });
});
```